# Why is this command starting endless terminals and how to make it work?

Tags: bash, gnome-terminal, scripts, zsh

```
#!/bin/bash
gnome-terminal --command='/home/user23/bin/n-youtube-dl "$1"'
```

I want to pass the argument passed to this script to the other script started in the terminal. But this starts endless gnome terminals.

Can you explain why that is and how to make this work?

I am running zsh has my main shell if that matters, the terminal starts the script in zsh then I guess.

Update:

```
#!/bin/bash
gnome-terminal --command='echo "WTF"'
read -p "Press [Enter] key"
```

Is just closing the term faster then I can see WTF. Isn't it supposed to stop? Same goes for replacing the `WTF` with `$1` again, no respawn.

Comment: What does `/home/user23/bin/n-youtube-dl` look like?

Comment: https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/blob/master/youtube-dl I dont think that this matters at all.

Comment: ok, that doesn't seem to spawn a terminal, so it doesn't answer the question of why it's recursing. Are you sure `n-youtube-dl` is that python script and not actually your wrapper itself?

Comment: Actually I was wrong I just made a test and its just closing the term

Comment: Oh damn I am too tired, yes you are right, that was actaully the wrapper itself and I tought that it has something to do with the $1 lol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To run a command in `gnome-terminal`, and safely pass arguments to it, you should use the `-x` option, since this avoids having the line parsed by two shells.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
gnome-terminal -x youtube-dl "$@"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash
gnome-terminal -x bash -c "cd ~/Downloads/youtube; youtube-dl \"$@\"; read -p \"Press [Enter] key\""
```

This is how I actually solved this.

Comment: Don't embed the arguments into the script. That is very error prone. Instead, pass them on as arguments: `gnome-terminal -x bash -c 'cd ~/Downloads/youtube && youtube-dl "$@"; read -p "Press [Enter] key"' _ "$@"`